Why is using JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable to deserialize a 1GB file resulting in 2GB+ memory allocation?
I need to deserialize a 1GB json file one element at a time in a streaming fashion and after doing some reading found JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable to enable this while also keeping the memory usage somewhat low. I presumed this would effectively mean the memory usage wouldnt really peak above the size of a single json object in the collection (maybe a little more for other processes) and/or around the size of the json buffer which by default is 4MB (adjustable).
However after running the following benchmark .NET 8 the results were not what i was expecting - why was 2GB+ memory consumed during this process - have i grossly misunderstood what should be happening?
[MemoryDiagnoser(true)]
[Orderer(SummaryOrderPolicy.FastestToSlowest)]
[ShortRunJob]
public class DeserializationBenchmarks
{
    [Benchmark]
    public async Task StreamJsonAndDeserialize()
    {
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

        var peopleJson = File.OpenRead("./peeps.json"); //1GB+ 
        var people = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<Person>(peopleJson, options);

        await foreach (var person in people)
        {
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(person.Name);
        }
        await peopleJson.DisposeAsync();
    }
}


// The json file is just an array of this simple Person object

    public class Person
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
        public string Bio { get; set; }
        public double Version { get; set; }
    }


I've tried adjusting the buffer size but with no luck, I also tried nulling out each person object after its deserialized to ensure it gets GC'd (perhaps pointlessly) - I'm hoping to deserialize this file in a more memory efficient manor
UPDATE: This is the code used to generate the dataset
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
            var fixture = new Fixture { RepeatCount = 1 };

            var fileStream = File.Create("./people.json");
            var utf8JsonWriter = new Utf8JsonWriter(fileStream);

            utf8JsonWriter.WriteStartArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5_000_000; i++)
            {
                var person = fixture.Create<Person>();
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(utf8JsonWriter, person, options);
            }
            utf8JsonWriter.WriteEndArray();

            await utf8JsonWriter.DisposeAsync();
            await fileStream.DisposeAsync();

Running the code in an nunit test in order to look at the memory info resulting in the following:


I added the [tag:benchmarkdotnet] tag because I'm not sure we're reading its output correctly.  From the docs it looks like maybe the 2.25 GB might be the total number of bytes allocated, not the peak number allocated but not collected at any given time.  I don't use this tool though so I may be wrong.  If it's really the total number allocated not the peak number of bytes in use at any given time then I don't think you actually have a problem.

If it is the peak allocation not the total allocation, it may simply be that the GC doesn't kick in because it doesn't need to.  What happens if you call GC.Collect() for every 100 people?  And what happens if you replace await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(person.Name) with something that, say, adds the length of the name to some running total?  The .NET Console class is fairly heavy and might be remembering history somewhere.

For proper memory analysis you need to use a proper memory profiler, such as dotMemory or ANTS, to see what is actually being held. Anything else is guessing in the dark. On a side note, instead of manually disposing you should use using var peopleJson and using var people.

await using peopleJson = File.OpenRead("./peeps.json"); might be better still.  And I don't think the return of JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<T>() is actually disposable.

How many Person objects do you create? Each on will create 4 string references (64-bit, I'm guessing) and space for a double (64-bit) plus the allocations for the strings. The way you have the code written, each of those allocations will be part of Gen0 and will be cleaned up at very little cost at the next GC. I don't know any way that you can provide your own person object (perhaps out of a pool) for the deserialization, but no matter what, you'd pay for the strings. In a GC-based framework you need to understand that memory will spike (particularly when dealing with gigabyte streams

@dbc According this doc it states "Allocated contains the size of allocated managed memory. Stackalloc/native heap allocations are not included. It’s per single invocation, inclusive." Also I've tried adding GC.Collect and it doesnt appear to fair much better.

@Charlieface I ran the same code in an nunit unit test - and had a look at the memory usage in Diagnostic Tools in visual studio and the Process Memory gradually increases (updated the question with a screenshot). I definitely need to do a bit more reading up on memory management and how to interpret the results properly

@Flydog57 The json file contains 5 million person objects. I'll update the question with code used to generate the dataset

Then clearly GC hasn't run, because those objects should have been collected.

If you call GC.Collect you are requesting a collection, but it isn't scheduled immediately. If you call GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers (after the Collect call) it will block your thread until the GC completes. Using memory that can be collected in Gen0 is not expensive

If you want to see very different behavior, complie and run your code as 32-bit. The Person objects will shrink by nearly half, but your process only gets 2 gig of virtual memory. Eventually, your code will put memory pressure_ on the GC and it will kick in, collecting all those Persons that are no longer used. If you look at it with an accurate memory measurement (I like PerfMon with the .NET memory counters, you will see the characteristic sawtooth pattern of memory usage. 2 gig is a ton on 32 bit, it's nothing on 64 but.

Honestly I cant say I know the reason for why its happening, I have guesses.
Maybe the GC doesnt kick in as it doesnt see its necessary yet, I wonder what would happen if you ran it in a system with lower memory?
I have 2 solutions:
You can use Cinchoo ETL, https://github.com/Cinchoo/ChoETL an open source, well ETL library for dotnet. and then use it for example as so:
foreach (dynamic e in new ChoJSONReader("Emp.json"))
    Console.WriteLine("Id: " + e.Id + " Name: " + e.Name);

(reference: https://github.com/Cinchoo/ChoETL/wiki/QuickJSONLoad)
If that doesnt work for your use case, How about reading and parsing the json intermediately, in batches?
